# I can't optimize a check for out-of-order bills

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bills must be consecutive by date and number. I'm doing this query to check that I don't have out-of-order bills, but the performance is awful (I have millions of bills, so it takes minutes to check a month) :

```
SELECT NUMBER, DATE
FROM BILLS
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO AND
      EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM BILLS OUT_OF_ORDER
              WHERE OUT_OF_ORDER.NUMBER < BILLS.NUMBER
              AND OUT_OF_ORDER.DATE > BILLS.DATE)
```

I already have indexes by NUMBER, DATE and DATE + NUMBER, but the compound index can't really be used in that query.

I have also tried removing the subquery with no noticeable difference.

```
SELECT DISTINCT BILLS.NUMBER, BILLS.DATE
FROM BILLS
INNER JOIN BILLS OUT_OF_ORDER ON OUT_OF_ORDER.NUMBER < BILLS.NUMBER AND
                                 OUT_OF_ORDER.DATE > BILLS.DATE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO
```

Do you know how this kind of queries (using the >< operands on two different fields at the same time) can be improved ?.

I have added the execution plan. The problem obviously is on checking the OUT_OF_ORDER bills, it just uses the plain DATE index. As far as I know you can't define a compound index that allows you to search with >< operands on two different fields.

[image]

Comment: You have to enter more details. What is "the performance is awful"? How long does the query take? Try and place the execution plan in : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ Ps: when you ask the execution plan, management studio doesn't suggest an index creation, or something else?

Comment: Without a query plan, we're just guessing - but I guess it's because the "OUT_OF_ORDER" join needs to consider nearly all of your records. Is there a way to restrict this further - do bills get out of order across the decades, or can you do something like OUT_OF_ORDER.DATE > BILLS.DATE + 10 days

Comment: I have added the execution plan. It takes more than a minute to calculate the out-of-order bills of a month. @NevilleK I use yearly series, so I can only further restrict it within the current year.

Comment: Could you please post a schema (with indexes)?

Comment: @NevilleK the real table has many more fields (series, etc. ...) it would only confuse us. I'm quite certain that the real problem is how searches NUMBER < XXXX and DATE > YYYY should be optimized. Maybe I should drop this question and start a new one asking just that.

Comment: Are there gaps in `number` values?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever they shouldn't be, but I also have a different query to check it. This second check performs fine because it can use the primary key : and not exists (select * from BILLS GAP where GAP.NUMBER = BILLS.NUMBER + 1)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks Damien, you made me realize that I don't need to check all previous bills but just the immediate one. This will allow me to use the primary key for that check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever made me remember that I have no gaps (or I shouldn't have them, which is verified on a second query). So I can just check the one previous bill and not all the previous bills.

Checking the previous bill uses the primary key, because I directly look for the bill NUMBER - 1.

Now this query only takes a few seconds instead of a few minutes.

```
SELECT BILLS.NUMBER, BILLS.DATE
FROM BILLS
INNER JOIN BILLS OUT_OF_ORDER ON OUT_OF_ORDER.NUMBER = BILLS.NUMBER - 1 AND
                                 OUT_OF_ORDER.DATE > BILLS.DATE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO
```

Thank you all.